# Yii URL Manger create a route with multi optional parameters

Tags: php, regex, yii, yii1.x

I have a URL rule with multiple optional parameters and it was working but it stopped after I upgraded from Yii 1.1.15 to 1.1.19.

```
const OPTIONAL_PARAMS = '(/<featured:featured>)?'
. '(/subType/<subType:.*?>)?'
. '(/type/<type:\d+>)?'
. '(/category/<category:.*>)?';


'<lang:(en|fr)>/reports'. OPTIONAL_PARAMS => 'reports',
```

Any one can provide me some ideas or someone faced similar issues?

P.S. The other URL manager rules are working fine, only this one with `(SOME_CODE)?` for optional params is not working. I'm using PHP 5.6 and Apache.

Comment: Did you tried to remove duplicated slash in your rule (after `reports` - `'<lang:(en|fr)>/reports' . OPTIONAL_PARAMS => 'reports',`)?

Comment: can you describe a bit more, what you mean by stopp, does it show you blank page, incoreectpage or an error?

Comment: it redirects to 404 and the URLs will work if removed the question mark and made the params not optional, and yes I already removed the duplicate slash

Comment: I found one difference so far, the old site was running on 1.1.15 version while the new site is running on 1.1.19

Comment: I replaced the yii1.1.19 with 1.1.15 and all urls  are working now, but how can I fix that  and enable 1.1.19 again??

Comment: can you confirm if it works correctly with 1.1.17 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in by [this issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/4051). But in short: this syntax (regexp outside of named params) was never officially supported and it was removed as a bugfix in Yii 1.1.17.

The last version which supports this is 1.1.16, but it is really old and I would not recommend using it. You should probably create custom UrlRule and use it instead of `CUrlRule` for this particular case.

---

You may also try to add `/*` at the end of the pattern, like this:

```
'<lang:(en|fr)>/reports/*' => 'reports',
```

This will allow to append GET params to URL as `/key/value`. So this:

```
$this->createUrl('reports', [
    'type' => 'sometype', 
    'category' => 'somecategory',
    'lang' => 'en',
]);
```

will create URL like:

```
/en/reports/type/sometype/category/somecategory
```